# Changing string after hooking WM_SETTEXT

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have setup a hook on WM_SETTEXT message using WH_CALLWNDPROC.

In hook procedure

```
CWPSTRUCT* info = (CWPSTRUCT*) lParam;
wchar_t *wsz = NULL;
switch(info->message)
{
case WM_SETTEXT:
wsz = (wchar_t *) info->lParam;
//info->lParam = (LPARAM) L"Hello";
//SendMessage(info->hWnd,WM_SETTEXT,0,(LPARAM)L"HEllo");
//SetWindowText(info->hWnd,L"Hello");


break;
}
```

Is it possible to change the string as done above in the code.
I tried by using APIs like

```
SendMessage(info->hWnd,WM_SETTEXT,0,(LPARAM)L"HEllo");
SetWindowText(info->hWnd,L"Hello");
```

But none of them working.Idea here is to hook WM_SETTEXT message and change the string before it reached destination window.

Comment: Hooks are for observation, not modification... Not sure what you're trying to do, but I don't think hooks are the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` doesn't allow you to modify messages, the documentation for [CallWndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644975%28VS.85%29.aspx) directly states this.

The `WH_GETMESSAGE` does allow you to modify the message.  See the documentation for [GetMsgProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644981%28VS.85%29.aspx).  However, this probably won't work for what you want since it only messages that are retrieved with GetMessage() or PeekMessage() and send messages call the WndProc directly rather than using the message queue.

The way to do what you want is to use the `WH_CBT` hook and listed for `HCBT_CREATEWND` events.  Then subclass the window as it is created and handle the `WM_SETTEXT` message.